# How to combine many objects into one array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am probably WAY off on this but being new I'm trying to figure it out :) HEY I got this far.....

```
parser(body, (err, result)=> {
                if(result.hasOwnProperty('feed')){
                    var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.feed.entry));
                    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){ 
                       var tube = result[i];
                       var tLink = tube.link[0].$.href;
                       var title = tube.title;
                       var id = tube['yt:videoId'][0];
                       var pic = tube['media:group'][0]['media:thumbnail'][0].$.url;
                       var results = {
                           url : tLink,
                           title : title[0],
                           thumb: pic,
                           id: id
                       };
    //WORKS FROM HERE UP NO ISSUES..trying to combine them all into one array of objects so below this is where I'm not having any luck :)
                       var res = [];
                       for (var j = 0; j < results; j++){
                          console.log(results[j]);
                          res.push(results[j]); 
                       }

                       this.sendSocketNotification("TUBE_RESULT", res);
```

It is not working and I've tried to find ANY info I could on this....

It's returning single objects but I want them all in one array...

Suggestions or help would be GREATLY appreciated!! :)

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

This is what I am currently getting:

[image]

Comment: is your loop running for the entire length of results ?
Also please console out the res array outside the loop.

Comment: If I do that I get nothing.   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through your object and get them into an array. I'm using `keys` array of the object to achieve this.

```
var results = {
  url : tLink,
  title : title[0],
  thumb: pic,
  id: id
};

var arr = Object.keys(results).map(function (key) { 
   return results[key]; 
});

res.push(arr[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you define results as :

```
var results = {
  url : tLink,
  title : title[0],
  thumb: pic,
  id: id
};
```

and then

```
for (var j = 0; j < results; j++){
   console.log(results[j]);
   res.push(results[j]);   
}
```

results is an object, you need integer on the for statement. maybe what you want is result instead of results ??

Answer (score 0):

I want to Thank ALL of you for your help here's the answer:

```
parser(body, (err, result) => {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty('feed')) {
                    var entries = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.feed.entry)),
                        results = [];
                    for (var i = 0, entry; entry = entries[i]; i++) results.push({
                        'tLink': entry.link[0].$.href,
                        'title': entry.title[0],
                        'id': entry['yt:videoId'][0],
                        'pic': entry['media:group'][0]['media:thumbnail'][0].$.url
                    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try changing your for loop:

```
var res = [];
for (var j = 0; j < results; j++){
    console.log(results[j]);
    res.push(results[j]);   
}
```

to a for-in loop:

```
var res = [];
for (var j in results){
    console.log(j + ": " + results[j]);
    res.push(results[j]);   
}
```